# Does MultiPolygon support Altitude?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geojson

I have a GeoJSON of type MultiPolygon that includes altitudes. When loading it with Earth Engine (`ee.FeatureCollection`), I receive an error, that the Geometry is invalid. The underlying code suggests that the MultiPolygon must only have arrays of 2 elements.

This is an example MultiPolygon I am using: `[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]`

Does MultiPolygon only supports 2D coordinates?

Comment: Your test geometry is invalid with or without z because any polygon must have at least 3 distinct points.

Comment: Agree, the real data has different points, I just wanted to anonymize it here. But it looks like ee doesnt support Z values at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earth Engine doesn't support Z values in any of the geometry coordinates.